# display parsing json to radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I want to loop data of json and display to the radio button on html,

```
var link = "http://localhost/codeigniter/load";
var selector = "#result-media-uploader";
$.getJSON(link,function(data){
        $.each(data,function(i,item){
            var openTag = "<div class='col-lg-2'>";
            var closeTag = "</div>";

            openTag += "<input id='media-radio' type='radio' name='media-radio' value='"+item.id+"'>";
            openTag += "<label class='label'><img width='100%' height='100%' src='"+item.post_content+item.post_title+"'></label>";
            openTag += closeTag;

            $(selector).append(openTag);
        });
});
```

request is sended but in the output is none.. 
this is the server code

```
$data = $this->db->where('post_type','attachment')->where('post_mine_type','image')
        ->get('cs_posts')->result_array();
        return json_encode($data);
```

I'm new on javascript, can you explain my mistake.. thanks for your help..

Comment: console.log( data ) and show whats the result ?

Comment: i try this    $.getJSON(link,function(data){
                   $(selector).append(console.log(data));
                }); then the output is none.. xD

Comment: no buddy you just do that `$.getJSON(link,function(data){ console.log(data) });` and check in your firebug

Comment: i get nothing.. i dont have firebug, but i use chrome developer tool.. i see ajax was sended but i dont get callback.. then i try to print_r() the data on server side.. and i get json data..

Comment: try `echo json_encode($data);`, instead of `return\`

Comment: thanks @Ghost i get the picture but i just get 1 picture.. i get 5 response picture but just display one.. xD

Comment: ok i was fix it.. thanks very much guys.. (y)  Agha Umair Ahmed, Ghost and hari..

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    openTag += "<label class='label'><img width='100%' height='100%' src='"+item.post_content+""+item.post_title+"'></label>";
    $("+selector+").append(openTag);
```

Comment: im sorry friend, but i get nothing.. xD

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys.. (y)

this the final code..

js file
    var folder = "/codeigniter";
    var url = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host+folder+"/admin/uploads/load";

```
$('#refresh-media-uploader').click(function(){
    $.getJSON(url,function(data){
        $.each(data,function(i,item){
            var openTag = "<div class='row'><div class='col-lg-2'>";
            var closeTag = "</div></div>";

            openTag += "<input id='media-radio' type='radio' name='media-radio' value='"+item.id+"'>";
            openTag += "<label class='label'><img width='100%' height='100%' src='"+item.post_content+"100x100-"+item.post_title+"'></label>";
            openTag += closeTag;

            $("#result-media-uploader").append(openTag);
        });
    });
});
```

and sirver side

```
$data = $this->db->where('post_type','attachment')->where('post_mine_type','image')
        ->get('cs_posts')->result_array();
        echo json_encode($data);
```